# Angular async ngOnInit instantiating a needed property

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, ngoninit

I have a property in an Angular component, instantiated through a service inside `async ngOnInit`:

```
txtItems: TextItems[];
 
constructor(private textItemService: TextItemService) {}

async ngOnInit() {    
    // await on promise
    this.txtItems = await this.textItemService.getAllAsync();
}
```

where `getAllAsync` returns a promise:

```
async getAllAsync(): Promise<TextItems[]> {
   return await this.http.get<TextItems[]>(this.url).toPromise();
}
```

`ngOnInit` runs asynchronously so that the page doesn't have to hang until items are loaded (which is a good thing), but sometimes `this.txtItems` is accessed from the template before it has finished loading, which results in an exception.

I can make `ngOnInit` not `async`, but then the page will load slowly.

Should I use `txtItems: Promise<TextItems[]>` or something like that, and then access it from everywhere using the `async` pipe? What is the correct approach when waiting for async services?

Comment: Please show how `getAllAsync()` is defined.

Comment: @MichaelD: sorry, updated. It just returns a promise around a http get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of converting an observable to a promise without any substantiated advantages. And given that the output from the HTTP request is used only in the template, you could return the observable from service and use it's value in the template using `async` pipe.

**Service**

```js
getAllAsync(): Observable<TextItems[]> {
   return this.http.get<TextItems[]>(this.url);
}
```

**Component**

```js
public txtItems$: Observable<TextItems[]>;

constructor(private textItemService: TextItemService) {
  this.txtItems$ = this.textItemService.getAllAsync();   // <-- no `await`, only assignment
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(txtItems$ | async) as txtItems">
  <!-- use `txtItems` -->
</ng-container>
```